# Proper inclusion for $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to answer the following question:
"Suppose that $f: D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function and $A \subseteq D$. Prove that $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$ and give an example of when the inclusion is proper."

The proof for $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$ is rather trivial: "If $x \in A$, then $f(x) \in f(A)$, and $x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$. Thus, $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$."

The thing I'm struggling with is finding a specific example. Any tips?

Comment: Your proof is wrong. You seem to misunderstand the meaning of $f^{-1}(X)$ for a set $X$.

Comment: Should I get rid of the $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a function that is not injective.

Take $D=\mathbb R$, $f(x)=x^2$, $A=\{2\}$. Then $f(A)=\{4\}$ and $f^{-1}(f(A))=\{-2,2\} \supsetneq A$.

Comment: Alright, that's what I had in mind. I know that, in general, $f^{-1}(f(A)) \not \subseteq A$. This is only true when $f$ is injective, if I recall correctly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you mean $\{-2,2\}\subsetneq A=\{2\}$ instead?